# Hamiltonian reduction in symplectic geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

If $V$ is symplectic and $W^\perp \subseteq W\subseteq V$, then why is $W$ a pre-symplectic vector space? Why is $W/W^\perp$ symplectic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is symplectic, then it comes equipped with a symplectic form $\omega$. Then $\omega|_W$ is a skew-symmetric bilinear form on $W$, so that $(W, \omega|_W)$ is a pre-symplectic vector space.

To see that $W/W^\perp$ is symplectic, we need to check that $\omega|_W$ descends to a non-degenerate $2$-form on $W/W^\perp$. The natural pre-symplectic form on $W/W^\perp$ is
$$\bar{\omega}: W/W^\perp \otimes W/W^\perp \longrightarrow \Bbb R,$$
$$\bar{\omega}([w], [v]) = \omega(w, v),$$
where $w$ (respectively $v$) is any choice of representative for $[w]$ (respectively $[v]$). It is trivial to check that $\bar{\omega}$ is well-defined since any two representatives of an element of $W/W^\perp$ differ by an element of $W^\perp$. To see that $\bar{\omega}$ is non-degenerate, suppose that for some fixed $[w] \in W/W^\perp$,
$$\bar{\omega}([w],[v]) = 0 \text{ for all } [v] \in W/W^\perp.$$
This is equivalent to saying
$$\omega(w, v) = 0 \text{ for any representative } w \text{ of } [w] \text{ and all } v \in W.$$
This implies that any representative $w$ of $[w]$ is an element of $W^\perp$, and hence $[w] = 0$. Therefore $\bar{\omega}$ is non-degenerate and $(W/W^\perp, \bar{\omega})$ is a symplectic vector space.